# Print contents of a list box as comma-separated values using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box defined as shown below. I want to print out the name and email address of each item in the select box as comma seperated values, like

```
Tom Wayne,tom@xyz.com
Joe Parker,joe@xyz.com
Peter Simons,peter@xyz.com
```

Any way to accomplish that using JQuery?

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="search_results">
<option  value="tom@xyz.com">Tom Wane</option>
<option value="joe@xyz.com">Joe Parker</option>
<option value="peter@xyz.com">Peter Simons</option>
</select>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select").each(function() {
    var options = [];
    $(this).children("option").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        options.push($this.text()+ "," + $this.val());
    });
    alert(options.join("\n"));
});
```

This will alert you the options for each select individually.

Answer (score 10):

I think is a good example to use [Traversing/map](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map):

```
$('select option').map(function () {
  return $(this).text() + ',' + $(this).val();
}).get().join('\n');
```

Comment: Why does map() return the Jquery object? Do you have an example where get isn't used after map?

Comment: Thanks for the reply CMS. But,the code just prints out the names not the email address !.

Comment: Scott, try it out here: http://jsbin.com/acoga ... it *does* print the email addresses, exactly in the way you requested it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var s = "";
$("select option").each(function()
{
   var $option = $(this);
   s += $option.text() + ", " + $option.val() + "\n";
});

alert(s);
```